# Session variable from Select Option

Tags: php

I am trying to help users with filling form in the case if their submission was not successfully send.. The first part of the code down below works fine, but the second part is not "detected". Even if the statement is false Select Pair is not shown.

HTML output:

```
<option selected='selected'> </option>
```

This is just a small piece of my script.

Any suggestion how to fix this? Thanks!

```
if(isset($_SESSION['pair'])) {

echo "<option selected='selected'> " . $_SESSION['pair'] . "</option>";

} else {

echo "<option disabled='disabled'>Select Pair</option>";

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the statement is false? `isset()` only checks if the session variable exists. It doesn't check if it's empty or not. You need to use `empty()` instead of `isset()` for that.

Comment: Yes.. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

unset($_SESSION['pair']);

And run the code again. Chances you didn't properly unset it hence only the first part work.